# Do We need IISRESET after SharePoint 2013 Clearing the Configuration Cache?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, timer-jobs, cache

I have a 10 server SharePoint Farm and now i am planning to clear the configuration cache by following below mentioned Steps.

1. Stop the “SharePoint 2013 Timer” service
2. Delete all the XML files in the config cache. There are loads of XML files that can be found in the folder “C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\SharePoint\Config\”  %SystemDrive%\ProgramData\Microsoft\SharePoint\Config\
3. Back up the Cache.ini file. (Make a copy of it. DO NOT DELETE THIS FILE, Only the XML files in the next step)
4. Delete all the XML configuration files in the GUID folder (DO NOTE DELETE THE FOLDER). Do this so that you can verify that the GUID folders content is replaced by new XML configuration files when the cache is rebuilt.
5. When you empty the configuration cache in the GUID folder, make sure that you do NOT delete the GUID folder and the Cache.ini file that is located in the GUID folder.
6. Double-click the Cache.ini file.
7. On the Edit menu, click Select All.
8. On the Edit menu, click Delete.
9. Type 1, and then click Save on the File menu. (Basically when you are done, the only text in the config.ini file should be the number 1)
10. Start the “SharePoint 2013 Timer” service.

***Do I need an IISRset after that ?***

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need to perform an IIS reset.